# I need to automate running commands in CMD with a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need help with a project. My goal is to open a batch program that will open CMD, then automatically run a few commands. I have tried a couple scripts that I found online. What happens is that CMD opens, shows a few errors like "End is not an internal or external command.", then it closes. It would be very helpful if one of you guys gave me a batch script that I could input my commands into, then make into a batch program.

Also, I don't think this will matter but I am running Windows 8.1 on a 64-Bit Computer.

P.S. Here Is the Script I used before:

```
Private Sub CMDAutomate()
    Dim sipdomain As TextBox = txtCommand
    Dim myprocess As New Process
    Dim StartInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    StartInfo.FileName = "cmd"
    StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    myprocess.StartInfo = StartInfo
    myprocess.Start()
    Dim SR As System.IO.StreamReader = myprocess.StandardOutput
    Dim SW As System.IO.StreamWriter = myprocess.StandardInput
     SW.WriteLine(**Command I want to enter**)
    SW.WriteLine(**Command I want to enter**)
    SW.WriteLine(**Command I want to enter**)
    SW.WriteLine(**Command I want to enter**)
    SW.WriteLine(**Command I want to enter**)
    SW.WriteLine("exit")
    Results = SR.ReadToEnd
    SW.Close()
    SR.Close()
    Invoke(Finished)
End Sub
```

Comment: You saw that error because `end` _isn't_ a batch command. You should edit your question to include the code you have tried.

Comment: That's vbscript... or at least some dialect of Visual Basic.

Comment: @TheMajorOfMinecraft are you asking how to start this VBS from batch?

Comment: or what is an all new script that can be run from batch

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please improve your English.

It sounds like you want to run commands with

```
SW.WriteLine(**Command I want to enter**)
SW.WriteLine(**Command I want to enter**)
SW.WriteLine(**Command I want to enter**)
SW.WriteLine(**Command I want to enter**)
SW.WriteLine(**Command I want to enter**)
```

In that case, there is a Sendkeys.Send() class in .NET, which you can use.
Try Sendkeys.Send()

I do C#, not VB. But I think that will work

Comment: so what would be the whole script altogether?

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click in empty space in windows explorer
2. New>Shortcut
3. Type the location of the item: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k command1 & commmand2 & command3
4. Name your shortcut. Example- 'automate'

Double click the created shortcut, and your commands will run one by one.